# Use twitchAPI with cake

Tags: cakephp

since a few hours i'm trying to implement the twitchAPI in my cake projet. a long time ago i made this little script in basic php.

```
    $channelName = "gamespot"; 
    $json_file = @file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel={$channelName}", 0, null, null);
    $json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);                                                 
            @$json_array[0] && $json_array[0]['name'] == "live_user_{$channelName}";
                @$title = $json_array[0]['channel']['status'];
                @$game = $json_array[0]['meta_game'];
                @$chanel_view = $json_array[0]['channel_count'];
                @$totalchanelview = $json_array[0]['channel_view_count'];
```

but i don't know how to add this lines on my controller
For know i've just find this

```
public function twitch() {
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=manvsgame');
    $twitch = json_decode($json);
    $totalchanelview = $twitch[0]['channel_view_count'];
    $this->set('twitch', 'totalchanelview');
}
```

but of course i've this error

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Users/*****/Desktop/Websites/******/app/Controller/UsersController.php on line 29

anyone can explain to me how i can use this API?
thanks in advance and have a nice day/night :)

---

okey first thanks to help me. i still have a little "logic problem"

my function is something like that:

```
public function twitch() {
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=gamespot');
    $twitch = json_decode($json, true);
    $this->set('json', $twitch);
}
```

but know, what can I write to my view to see my informations (like the title of my stream for exemple.

I test with

```
echo $twitch[0]['title']; (it's my line 1)
```

bit i've this error

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: twitch [APP/View/Users/admin_dashboard.ctp, line 1]

Comment: What's line 29? Both your snippets are very different. And `$this->set('twitch', 'totalchanelview');` should be `$this->set('twitch', $totalchanelview);`.(but not relevant to your error)

Answer (score 0):

```
$twitch = json_decode($json, true); // add true param
$twitch[0]['channel_view_count'];
```

adding `true` returns the data as an associated array instead